# JMeter Select a random item from the category and add it to the cart

Tags: jmeter

I need to test the e-shop
Flow is similar to select any category> select any product > Add to Cart. 
Could you advise me how to choose any random product and add it to the cart
I use JMeter 5.1.1

Answer (score -2):

Choosing a random product is basically sending a [HTTP Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) with parameter(s) indicating the product, normally it would be something like:

1. [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) of the product
2. Product ID
3. Product code

So you need to use a suitable JMeter [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), in the majority of cases for web applications it would be [CSS Selector Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter/) to fetch either random or all products for later re-use.

If you need more comprehensive answer you'll either need to share the link to the webpage you're testing or provide partial [DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) having 2 products as a part of your question.